# Problema con un método para contar pixeles en una imagen con JAVA

Tags: java

BUenas noches muchachos tengo un inconveniente y es que no puedo solucionarlo, me aparece este error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

mi codigo es:

```
public int cuantosPixelColor(Color colorBuscado)

{

int contador=0;

for( int i = 0; i < alto; i++ )

for( int j = 0; j < ancho; j++ )

{

if(darColorPixel(i,j).equals(colorBuscado))

{

contador ++;

}

}

return contador;

}
```

adjunto el modelo de clases:
[image: modelo de clases]

Comment: Favor de especificar el formato de tu imágen, por ejemplo si es un bmp se forma de una matriz cuadrada si es blanco y negro o de tres matrices si es a color, cosa que no debería de importar ya que Java se encarga de la manipulación de bits mediante sus clases para manipulación de imágenes.

Comment: No sabemos qué retorna darColorPixel

Comment: en este link está el código a partir del cuál se debe construir el metodo cuantosPixelesColor(colorBuscado)  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/350886/retorna-el-n%c3%bamero-de-pixeles-que-tienen-el-color-dado-como-par%c3%a1metro