# Retorna el número de pixeles que tienen el color dado como parámetro

Tags: java

Me piden construir un método que devuelva el número de pixeles en la imagen cuyo color es el dado como parámetro. Ayuda: No olvide que los objetos deben compararse con el método equals.

A partir del siguiente código:

```
/**
 * Imagen de mapa de colores
 */
public class Imagen
{
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constantes
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Ancho máximo de la imagen
     */
    public static final int ANCHO_MAXIMO = 400;

    /**
     * Alto máximo de la imagen
     */
    public static final int ALTO_MAXIMO = 300;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Atributos
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Matriz de colores de la imagen
     */
    private Color bitmap[][];

    /**
     * Ancho de la imagen
     */
    private int ancho;

    /**
     * Alto de la imagen
     */
    private int alto;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructores
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Crea una imagen a partir de la ruta del archivo donde esta la imagen original en BMP. La imagen numera los píxeles desde la esquina superior izquierda de la imagen con
     * (0,0). La coordenada X ve de 0 hasta el ancho-1 y la coordenada Y va de 0 a el alto-1 Si la imagen es de ancho mayor al ANCHO_MAXIMO o con altura mayor a ALTO_MAXIMO,
     * la imagen se recorta hasta los límites.
     * @param archivo Nombre y ruta del archivo. archivo != null.
     * @throws IOException Error al leer el archivo
     */
    public Imagen( String archivo ) throws IOException
    {
        bitmap = new Color[ALTO_MAXIMO][ANCHO_MAXIMO];
        cargarImagen( archivo );
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Métodos
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Retorna el color de un píxel según su ubicación en la imagen
     * @param x Coordenada horizontal
     * @param y Coordenada vertical
     * @return el color del píxel de coordenadas (x,y) o null en caso de que las coordenadas no estén sobrepasen los límites de la imagen.
     */
    public Color darColorPixel( int x, int y )
    {
        if( x >= ancho || y >= alto )
            return null;
        else
            return bitmap[ y ][ x ];
    }

    /**
     * Retorna el alto en píxeles de la imagen
     * @return alto
     */
    public int darAlto( )
    {
        return alto;
    }

    /**
     * Retorna el ancho en píxeles de la imagen
     * @return ancho
     */
    public int darAncho( )
    {
        return ancho;
    }

    /**
     * Carga la imagen que se encuentra en el archivo
     * @param nombreArchivo - nombre y ruta del archivo
     * @throws IOException Error al cargar la imagen
     */
    private void cargarImagen( String nombreArchivo ) throws IOException
    {
        File archivo = new File( nombreArchivo );
        BufferedImage bmp;

        try
        {
            bmp = ImageIO.read( archivo );
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            throw new IOException( "No se encuentra la imagen" );
        }

        if( bmp.getWidth( ) < ANCHO_MAXIMO )
            ancho = bmp.getWidth( );
        else
            ancho = ANCHO_MAXIMO;

        if( bmp.getHeight( ) < ALTO_MAXIMO )
            alto = bmp.getHeight( );
        else
            alto = ALTO_MAXIMO;

        for( int i = 0; i < alto; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < ancho; j++ )
            {
                bitmap[ i ][ j ] = new Color( bmp.getRGB( j, i ) );
            }
    }

    /**
     * Retorna el mapa de bits como una BufferdImage
     * @return imagen como objeto BufferedImage
     */
    public BufferedImage darImagenBuffer( )
    {
        BufferedImage imagen = new BufferedImage( ancho, alto, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );
        for( int i = 0; i < alto; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < ancho; j++ )
            {
                imagen.setRGB( j, i, bitmap[ i ][ j ].getRGB( ) );
            }
        return imagen;
    }

    /**
     * Negativo de la imagen: El negativo se calcula cambiando cada componente RGB, tomando el valor absoluto de restarle al componente 255.
     */
    public void convertirNegativo( )
    {
        //Recorre la matriz y calcula los componentes del nuevo color
        for( int i = 0; i < alto; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < ancho; j++ )
            {
                Color colorViejo = bitmap[ i ][ j ];
                int nuevoR = Math.abs( colorViejo.getRed( ) - 255 );
                int nuevoG = Math.abs( colorViejo.getGreen( ) - 255 );
                int nuevoB = Math.abs( colorViejo.getBlue( ) - 255 );
                bitmap[ i ][ j ] = new Color( nuevoR, nuevoG, nuevoB );
            }
    }

    /**
     * Reflejar imagen: Consiste en intercambiar las columnas enteras de la imagen, de las finales a la iniciales
     */
    public void reflejarImagen( )
    {
        //Recorre la matriz hasta la mitad para intercambiar los colores de la columna
        for( int i = 0; i < alto; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < ancho / 2; j++ )
            {
                Color temporal = bitmap[ i ][ j ];
                bitmap[ i ][ j ] = bitmap[ i ][ ancho - 1 - j ];
                bitmap[ i ][ ancho - 1 - j ] = temporal;
            }
    }

    /**
     * Binarización: Consiste en llevar cada píxel de una imagen a negro o blanco. Para ello se requiere un umbral: si el color del píxel está por encima o igual se lleva a
     * blanco y si está por debajo se lleva a negro.
     * @param umbral Umbral para la binarización.
     */
    public void binarizarImagen( double umbral )
    {
        //Recorre la matriz de la imagen. Aquellos puntos con color menor o
        // igual al umbral los lleva a blanco y los mayores al negro.
        for( int i = 0; i < alto; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < ancho; j++ )
            {
                Color pixel = bitmap[ i ][ j ];
                int promedio = ( pixel.getBlue( ) + pixel.getGreen( ) + pixel.getRed( ) ) / 3;
                if( promedio < umbral )
                    bitmap[ i ][ j ] = Color.BLACK;
                else
                    bitmap[ i ][ j ] = Color.WHITE;
            }
    }

    /**
     * Pixelamiento: Consiste en dividir la imagen en pequeñas regiones de píxeles y para cada una de esas regiones cambiar el color de los píxeles al color promedio de dicha
     * región. En este ejemplo, la región se dimensiona con los divisores más pequeños del ancho y el alto de la imagen
     */
    public void pixelarImagen( )
    {
        //Los píxeles son divisores de las dimensiones de la imagen
        int anchoPixel = menorDivisorMayorAUno( ancho );
        int altoPixel = menorDivisorMayorAUno( alto );

        //Recorre la matriz por regiones para modificarla
        for( int x = 0; x < ancho; x += anchoPixel )
        {
            for( int y = 0; y < alto; y += altoPixel )
            {
                //Obtiene el color medio de la región
                Color colorPromedio = colorPromedio( x, y, x + anchoPixel - 1, y + altoPixel - 1 );
                //Cambia el color de la región al promedio
                cambiarColorRegion( colorPromedio, x, y, x + anchoPixel - 1, y + altoPixel - 1 );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Escala de grises: Para ello promedia los componentes de cada píxel y crea un nuevo color donde cada componente (RGB) tiene el valor de dicho promedio
     */
    public void convertirAGrises( )
    {
        //Recorre la matriz de la imagen. para pasarla a gris.
        for( int i = 0; i < alto; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < ancho; j++ )
            {
                int rgbGris = ( bitmap[ i ][ j ].getBlue( ) + bitmap[ i ][ j ].getGreen( ) + bitmap[ i ][ j ].getRed( ) ) / 3;
                bitmap[ i ][ j ] = new Color( rgbGris, rgbGris, rgbGris );
            }
    }

    /**
     * Convolución: Opera la imagen con la matriz de convolución dada por el usuario
     * @param convolucion Matriz cuadrada de dimensión impar. convolucion != null.
     * @param dimension Dimensión de la matriz de convolución. dimension es válido para el contenido de la matriz.
     */
    public void aplicarOperadorConvolucion( double[][] convolucion, int dimension )
    {
        //Obtiene una copia de la imagen original, pero con un marco
        //de píxeles negros para operar fácilmente las esquinas de la imagen
        //con la matriz de convolución
        Color copiaBorde[][] = copiarConBorde( dimension / 2 );

        //Calcula la suma de los factores de convolución
        double sumaConvolucion = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < dimension; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < dimension; j++ )
                sumaConvolucion += convolucion[ i ][ j ];

        //Recorre la matriz de píxeles para cambiar la imagen
        for( int i = 0; i < alto; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < ancho; j++ )
            {
                //Para cada píxel realiza el cálculo recorriendo la matriz de convolución
                double sumaRed = 0;
                double sumaGreen = 0;
                double sumaBlue = 0;

                //La división se hace en la mayoría de los casos (excepto en los bordes)
                //Restando sobre la suma de los factores de convolución
                double divisor = sumaConvolucion;

                //La suma se hace con los píxeles de la imagen original
                for( int k = -dimension / 2; k <= dimension / 2; k++ )
                    for( int l = -dimension / 2; l <= dimension / 2; l++ )
                    {
                        sumaRed += convolucion[ k + dimension / 2 ][ l + dimension / 2 ] * copiaBorde[ i + k + dimension / 2 ][ j + l + dimension / 2 ].getRed( );
                        sumaGreen += convolucion[ k + dimension / 2 ][ l + dimension / 2 ] * copiaBorde[ i + k + dimension / 2 ][ j + l + dimension / 2 ].getGreen( );
                        sumaBlue += convolucion[ k + dimension / 2 ][ l + dimension / 2 ] * copiaBorde[ i + k + dimension / 2 ][ j + l + dimension / 2 ].getBlue( );

                        //Si es un píxel del borde no cuenta para el divisor
                        if( i + l < 0 || i + l > alto || j + k < 0 || j + k > ancho )
                            divisor -= convolucion[ k + dimension / 2 ][ l + dimension / 2 ];
                    }

                if( divisor > 0 )
                {
                    sumaRed /= divisor;
                    sumaGreen /= divisor;
                    sumaBlue /= divisor;

                    if( sumaRed > 255 )
                        sumaRed = 255;
                    else if( sumaRed < 0 )
                        sumaRed = 0;

                    if( sumaGreen > 255 )
                        sumaGreen = 255;
                    else if( sumaGreen < 0 )
                        sumaGreen = 0;

                    if( sumaBlue > 255 )
                        sumaBlue = 255;
                    else if( sumaBlue < 0 )
                        sumaBlue = 0;

                    //Cambia el píxel en la imagen
                    bitmap[ i ][ j ] = new Color( ( int )sumaRed, ( int )sumaGreen, ( int )sumaBlue );
                }
                else
                {
                    if( sumaRed > 255 )
                        sumaRed = 255;
                    else if( sumaRed < 0 )
                        sumaRed = 0;

                    if( sumaGreen > 255 )
                        sumaGreen = 255;
                    else if( sumaGreen < 0 )
                        sumaGreen = 0;

                    if( sumaBlue > 255 )
                        sumaBlue = 255;
                    else if( sumaBlue < 0 )
                        sumaBlue = 0;

                    //Cambia el píxel en la imagen
                    bitmap[ i ][ j ] = new Color( ( int )sumaRed, ( int )sumaGreen, ( int )sumaBlue );
                }
            }
    }

    /**
     * Retorna el color promedio de la imagen
     * @return color promedio de toda la imagen
     */
    public Color colorPromedio( )
    {
        return colorPromedio( 0, 0, ancho - 1, alto - 1 );
    }

    /**
     * Busca el color promedio de la región de la imagen El color promedio es formado por los promedios de rojos, verdes y azules de cada píxel
     * @param xInicial Coordenada x del píxel de inicio.
     * @param yInicial Coordenada y del píxel de inicio.
     * @param xFinal Coordenada x del píxel final.
     * @param yFinal Coordenada y del píxel final.
     * @return Color promedio de la región.
     */
    private Color colorPromedio( int xInicial, int yInicial, int xFinal, int yFinal )
    {
        int valorMedioRojo = 0, valorMedioVerde = 0, valorMedioAzul = 0;
        int totalPixeles = ( xFinal - xInicial + 1 ) * ( yFinal - yInicial + 1 );

        //Recorre la región para promediar los componentes de los colores
        for( int i = yInicial; i <= yFinal; i++ )
            for( int j = xInicial; j <= xFinal; j++ )
            {
                valorMedioRojo += bitmap[ i ][ j ].getRed( );
                valorMedioVerde += bitmap[ i ][ j ].getGreen( );
                valorMedioAzul += bitmap[ i ][ j ].getBlue( );
            }

        valorMedioRojo /= totalPixeles;
        valorMedioVerde /= totalPixeles;
        valorMedioAzul /= totalPixeles;
        return new Color( valorMedioRojo, valorMedioVerde, valorMedioAzul );
    }

    /**
     * Calcula el menor divisor del número dado que sea mayor a 1.
     * @param numero al que se le buscará el divisor.
     * @return menor divisor mayor a uno del número
     */
    private int menorDivisorMayorAUno( int numero )
    {
        boolean encontrado = false;
        int divisor = 2;

        //Si el número es par el divisor menor es 2
        if( numero % divisor == 0 )
            return divisor;

        else
        {
            //Si el número es impar le busca un divisor impar
            divisor = 3;
            while( divisor < numero && !encontrado )
            {
                if( numero % divisor == 0 )
                    encontrado = true;
                else
                    divisor += 2;
            }
            return divisor;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Cambia el color de los píxeles de la región al dado como parámetro
     * @param color Color de la nueva región
     * @param xInicial Coordenada x del píxel de inicio
     * @param yInicial Coordenada y del píxel de inicio
     * @param xFinal Coordenada x del píxel final
     * @param yFinal Coordenada y del píxel final
     */
    private void cambiarColorRegion( Color color, int xInicial, int yInicial, int xFinal, int yFinal )
    {
        for( int i = yInicial; i <= yFinal && i < alto; i++ )
            for( int j = xInicial; j <= xFinal && j < ancho; j++ )
            {
                bitmap[ i ][ j ] = color;
            }
    }

    /**
     * Crea una copia de la imagen pero le adiciona un borde de píxeles de color negro, esto con el fin de poder operar con más facilidad la matriz de convolución con las
     * esquinas de la imagen, y sin alterar el resultado de los bordes
     * @param borde ancho en píxeles del borde (sobre un lado)
     * @return copia de la imagen (mapa de colores)
     */
    private Color[][] copiarConBorde( int borde )
    {
        //Crea una copia de la imagen original que incluye un marco de píxeles negros
        Color[][] copia = new Color[alto + 2 * borde][ancho + 2 * borde];

        //Recorre la imagen pero incluye el borde
        for( int i = 0; i < alto + borde * 2; i++ )
            for( int j = 0; j < ancho + borde * 2; j++ )
            {
                //Si el píxel es del borde, es de color negro
                if( i < borde || i >= alto + borde || j < borde || j >= ancho + borde )
                    copia[ i ][ j ] = Color.BLACK;
                else
                    //Si no lo toma de la imagen
                    copia[ i ][ j ] = new Color( bitmap[ i - borde ][ j - borde ].getRGB( ) );
            }
        return copia;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Puntos de Extensión
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Método de extensión 1
     * @return Respuesta 1
     */
    public String metodo1( )
    {
        return "Respuesta1 ";
    }

    /**
     * Método de extensión 2
     * @return Respuesta 2
     */
    public String metodo2( )
    {
        return "Respuesta 2";
    }
}
```

Lo que debo obtener es:

```
/**
* Retorna el número de pixeles que tienen el color dado como parámetro
* @param colorBuscado - Color de los pixeles a contar
* @return - Número de pixeles en la imagen con el color dado
```

Alguien me puede ayudar porfavor?

```
public int cuantosPixelColor(Color colorBuscado)

{

int contador=0;

for( int i = 0; i < alto; i++ )

for( int j = 0; j < ancho; j++ )

{

if(darColorPixel(i,j).equals(colorBuscado))

{

contador ++;

}

}

return contador;

}
```

Comment: Hola amigo ya pudiste resolver ese punto por que yo estoy presentando exactamente el mismo inconveniente.. de pronto ya tienes el código completo?

Comment: @christianalvarez sí, de hecho, ya aprobé el curso y en función de ello, creé un grupo de Whatsapp. En este grupo  ayudamos a otras personas a aprobar el curso apoyándonos, resolviendo dudas y sugerencias. https://chat.whatsapp.com/Fi4R2fE3C1AFKRbKi9nuSK

Comment: Estaría bien poner acá la respuesta correcta (como respuesta, no editando la pregunta) y marcarla como tal.

Comment: En resumen para el compilador de CupiExámenes hay que incluir si o si las llaves.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int cuantosPixelColor(Color colorBuscado)
{

   int contador=0;

   for( int i = 0; i < alto; i++ )
   {
     for(int j = 0; j < ancho;j++)
     {
       if(bitmap[i][j].equals(colorBuscado))
       {
         contador++;
       }
     } 
   }

   return contador;

}
```

Comment: Las respuestas que solo con código no son muy apropiadas, sería mejor que añadieras una explicación del por que eso soluciona el problema.